# how to exclude some elements from array

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

In some `.txt` files i have a line with some "categories".
A line (categories line) in a txt file looks like this:

```
athletics //category line
```

or

```
swim //category line
```

or

```
offside //category line offside, not visible for user
```

To avoid reading txt files which have category "offside", i use this code:

```
$blogfiles = glob("data/articles/*.txt"); // array with ALL blogfiles(articles)

// Exclude file(s) with category Offside    
$strip_cat = strtolower('Offside');

$offside_array = array();

foreach($blogfiles as $blogfile) { // Loop through the blogfiles in the directory   

    $handle = @fopen($blogfile, "r");

    if ($handle) {

        $lines = file($blogfile); //file into an array

        $buffer = $lines[1]; // this is the category line

        if(strpos(strtolower($buffer), $strip_cat) !== FALSE) { // strtolower; search word not case sensitive   

                $offside_array[] = $blogfile; // this array contains all the txt files which have "offside" in the category line

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}

// compare the arrays and strip out the blogfiles which contain cat Offside
$filtered_blogfiles = array_diff($blogfiles, $offside_array);
```

For making an archive, i want to use the archive year and name the category to that year.
So some txt files have now on the category line:

```
2019 //category line
```

or

```
2018 //category line
```

Also these categories (which have number of a year) should be excluded from the array.

So in my code i am looking for something like this:

```
$strip_cat = strtolower( array('Offside','2019','2018','2017','2016','2015') );
$excluded_array = array();
foreach($blogfiles as $blogfile) {
// and so on...
```

How can i achieve this in my current code?

Comment: You are using files instead of a dB for a specific reason?

Comment: @john for clarification reasons: The category of the blog article is always written in the second line of the text file?

Comment: yes! Always on the 2nd line of each txt file